How to solve the error "Explicit user authorization is required" when using Spotify Android SDK's auth-lib?
I am trying to connect my Android Studio app to my Spotify and I keep facing the following error message:
{"message":"Explicit user authorization is required to use Spotify. The user has to complete the auth-flow to allow the app to use Spotify on their behalf"}

The things that I have already tried/verified:

My Redirect URI is the name of my application followed by ://callback. It is also on my dashboard without any typos. My Client ID is the correct one too.
I have uploaded the correct SHA key on my dashboard.
I am using the Android Studio emulator which has Spotify installed and I've logged in using the same id that I am using for my Spotify Developer application.

My application seems to be throwing an error at the following line:
AuthorizationRequest.Builder builder = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(CLIENT_ID, AuthorizationResponse.Type.CODE, REDIRECT_URI);

response.getError() returns "Authentication Service Error Unknown" while the logcat returns:
{"message":"Explicit user authorization is required to use Spotify. The user has to complete the auth-flow to allow the app to use Spotify on their behalf"}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String CLIENT_ID = "xxxx";
private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "com.example.loopify_5://callback";
private SpotifyAppRemote mSpotifyAppRemote;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
        Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
        v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
        return insets;
    });


    authenticateSpotify();
}

private void authenticateSpotify() {
    AuthorizationRequest.Builder builder = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(CLIENT_ID, AuthorizationResponse.Type.CODE, REDIRECT_URI);
    builder.setScopes(new String[]{"streaming"});
    AuthorizationRequest request = builder.build();
    AuthorizationClient.openLoginActivity(this, 1337, request);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    // Check if result comes from the correct activity
    if (requestCode == 1337) {
        AuthorizationResponse response = AuthorizationClient.getResponse(resultCode, intent);
        switch (response.getType()) {
            // Response was successful and contains auth token
            case TOKEN:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                connectToSpotifyRemote();
                break;

            // Auth flow returned an error
            case ERROR:
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authorization error: " + response.getError() + response.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            // Most likely auth flow was cancelled
            default:
                // Handle other cases
        }
    }
}

private void connectToSpotifyRemote() {
    ConnectionParams connectionParams = new ConnectionParams.Builder(CLIENT_ID)
            .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
            .showAuthView(true)
            .build();

    SpotifyAppRemote.connect(this, connectionParams, new Connector.ConnectionListener() {

        public void onConnected(SpotifyAppRemote spotifyAppRemote) {
            mSpotifyAppRemote = spotifyAppRemote;
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Connected! Yay!");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected to Spotify Remote", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Now you can start interacting with App Remote
            connected();
        }

        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to connect to Spotify Remote", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("MainActivity", throwable.getMessage(), throwable);
            // Something went wrong when attempting to connect! Handle errors here
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ConnectionParams connectionParams =
            new ConnectionParams.Builder(CLIENT_ID)
                    .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
                    .showAuthView(true)
                    .build();

    SpotifyAppRemote.connect(this, connectionParams,
            new Connector.ConnectionListener() {

                public void onConnected(SpotifyAppRemote spotifyAppRemote) {
                    mSpotifyAppRemote = spotifyAppRemote;
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Connected! Yay!");

                    // Now you can start interacting with App Remote
                    connected();

                }

                public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.e("MyActivity", throwable.getMessage(), throwable);

                    // Something went wrong when attempting to connect! Handle errors here
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SpotifyAppRemote.disconnect(mSpotifyAppRemote);
}

private void connected() {
    // Play a playlist
    mSpotifyAppRemote.getPlayerApi().play("spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DX2sUQwD7tbmL");

    // Subscribe to PlayerState
    mSpotifyAppRemote.getPlayerApi()
            .subscribeToPlayerState()
            .setEventCallback(playerState -> {
                final Track track = playerState.track;
                if (track != null) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", track.name + " by " + track.artist.name);
                }
            });
}

}

https://www.reddit.com/r/truespotify/comments/xi6qiz/help_with_authorization_in_spotify_sdk_for_android/

I did check out that post, and this was OP's last message on that thread: "Sorry no, This was a blocker and a lack of upto date documentation turned me away from this project" :/

I see the same issue with the Kotlin example. In addition to the check/tests you did, I also tried: 1. editing the App on Spotify's dashboard to support the Android API only (to rule out an issue with the other APIs); 2. using http://localhost:3000/callback as redirect URI; 3. using a different redirect URI on the code vs the one registered on Spotify dashboard (somehow that trows exact the same error)
